# how to setup SVN REPOSITORY in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

how to get svn repository work in eclipse. i installed svn but cant find the location to repository other than link to it. http://wso2.org/library/67

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install a eclipse plugin for `svn`.

This [ibm developer works link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/) summarizes the steps and further shows to checkout a code from a svn repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should install an SVN plugin for Eclipse. I'd recommend that you use Subversive, here: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/